# SQL Server 2008: re increment table after deletion

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

using SQL Server 2008, using MS Visual Studio 2012 C# .NET4.5

I asked a similar question last week that was solved with the following query:

```
DECLARE @from int = 9, @to int = 3

UPDATE MainPareto 
SET pareto = m.new_pareto
FROM (
SELECT pKey, -- this is your primary key for the table
new_pareto = row_number() 
over(ORDER BY   CASE WHEN pareto = @from THEN @to ELSE pareto END, 
                CASE WHEN pareto = @from THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
FROM MainPareto
-- put in any conditions that you want to restrict the scores by.
WHERE PG = @pg AND pareto IS NOT NULL
-- end condtions
) as m
INNER JOIN MainPareto ON MainPareto.pKey = m.pKey
WHERE MainPareto.pareto <> m.new_pareto
```

As you can see this works great, incriments the "league" when changes are made.
Now after some functionality user has requested a deletion and recovery.

On my winform, the user can right click the grid and delete the "part" number.

The user can also recover if needed.

However, I need a Stored procedure that will resort the grid and update like this method does after a deletion from another stored procedure has been made, my Winform will sort that part out, but i do need a procedure that can do what my current one does for a deletion.

Hope you guys understand, if not ask me and ill try and clarify best I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not totally sure if this is what you are looking for, but this is how you can reseed your Primary Key column (if your primary key is also an `identity`). Notice how my insert after the truncate does not include Column 1 (the primary key column).

```
select *
into #temp
from MainPareto

truncate table MainPareto

insert into MainPareto (col2, col3, col4) --...
    select col2, col3, col4 --...
    from #temp
```